# What to do, Filter can't output html, angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have code like this:

```
<div> 
   {{ 'text:product description' | text }}
   <div> 
     {{ quantity }}
   </div> 
<div>
```

The **text** filter here takes the label on left, makes get request from server and get back the Text. Reason for this is to support different languages. So either get description in English, Spanish, Chinese, and so on.

However, specs have changed, people want to put Html code in the description. But Angular Expression `{{ .. }}` automatically escapes the html. So instead of html rendering it shows as `<b> Test </b>` instead of **`Test`** .

After trying to solve this problem it seems ONLY way Angular allows to put html is using [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) attribute. It works too. But it overrides all of the Html inside the element as expected.

And if you look at code above it will wipe out the div showing quantity.

Now how can i solve this?

I tried using directive link, compile, and more but due to being new maybe, i wasn't able to solve it. What is the good way to solve this problem. And is it how multiple languages are supported in SPA?

Angular 1.x